# CSS Style of HTML dropdown menu <option> <select>

Tags: html, css, html-select, background-color

I have a really annoying problem here
Stylesheets are here and here

As you can see, the background of that dropdown list is black, I cant find a way to make it grey or white. There are 2 really big stylesheets and I can't find where it says it should be black background and black font color. I don't even know why there are 2 Stylesheets, but I have to keep both, i can't just make a new one. Maybe merge them. 
I tried to style it with .TTWForm select .TTWForm option but it doesn't help, it is black background and black font, something you DONT EVER WANT TO HAPPEN.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the browser debug, and you will find out.

It's on the file `uniform.css`, starting at line 36:

```
div.selector {
    padding: 6px 6px;
    background:transparent url(../images/select-bg.jpg) no-repeat right top scroll;
}
```

Comment: That's where it SHOULD work, background-color works for Email field, Date field etc. but NOT for dropdown selection.

Comment: I've updated the answer... It's an image `../images/select-bg.jpg`. It is a black square

Comment: oh thanks, that's not what i wrote, so debugging is aweful. Thanks man :)